# React native web app served with apache2 server

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, apache2, config, deep-linking

I am trying to run a react native web app from an apache2 server. The app uses react-navigation library from @react-navigation/native-stack with linking={true}.

The app works well on local development machine with back and forward URL moves on the browser and using the below URLs

```
  http://localhost:19006/Market/Products
  http://localhost:19006/Market/Details?product_id=16
  http://localhost:19006/Market/Gallery
```

Moving the app onto an apache2 server on ubuntu. I am trying setup the configuration file. as below:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/lynnwood

<Directory /var/www/html/lynnwood/>
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
    Satisfy Any
</Directory>

    Alias /Market/Products  /var/www/html/lynnwood
    Alias /Market/Details  /var/www/html/lynnwood
    Alias /Market/Gallery  /var/www/html/lynnwood
```

I am always getting a 404 error on any URL except the home /
I just need the server to pass the url to the app without trying to locate files on the server path

Appreciate your help.

Comment: I think i figured it out, it seems apache2 URL checks are case sensitive. so /market/Products generates a 404 error while /Market/Products does not.
How can i disable the case sensitive checking ?